# R ggplots with anti-aliasing and wmf format on windows

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo, wmf

I'm trying to export a ggplot to word as an windows metafile on windows platform. Some suggest cairo to remove aliasing, but I need to save the plot as windows metafile, which don't work with wmf.
`ggsave(plot=plot,filename="plot.wmf",type="cairo")`

gives

`Error in grDevices::win.metafile(...) : unused argument (type = "cairo")`

Do anyone have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the ggsave documentation as it appears you're missing an argument. Looks like you need both a plot and a filename, and the cairo type isn't specified.

From what you have:
ggsave(plot.wmf,type="cairo")

To something like:
ggsave(plot = plot.wmf, "plot.wmf", type ="cairo-wmf")

More help from this resource: https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3777731

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy when typing the question. I have assigned the ggsave to a existing plot as you mentioned (see updated question). The problem is that cairo-wmf doesn't exist(?) and don't work. Same error occur.